# Multiple Spark Workers on Single Windows Machine

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cluster-computing

I am trying to teach myself Spark through Scala using Intellij on Windows. I'm doing this on a single machine, and I would like to start multiple workers on the single machine to simulate a cluster. I read [this page](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html) where it says that

*"The launch scripts do not currently support Windows. To run a Spark cluster on Windows, start the master and workers by hand."*

I don't know what it means to start the masters and workers by hand. Could anyone help? Many thanks for any help/suggestions.

Comment: You probably need to use Standalone, that means you have to set manually the master and the workers. Meaning, that you have to indicate the location, the memory that they will use, etc.

Comment: Thanks Alberto, I'm currently using Standalone successfully but I am unable to start multiple workers. What are the scripts that must be executed to launch multiple workers on a single machine?

Comment: @BenjiKok, if you are running on a single machine, your machine serves both as the master and as a single worker.

Comment: Thanks John, I've marked Naresh's suggestion as the answer since it allows for the registration of multiple workers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To manually start Spark Master, run below command from %SPARK_HOME%\bin

```
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
```

Above command will also print master URL like spark://ip:port
Master UI can be accessed at localhost:8080

To start Spark Worker, run

```
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://ip:port
```

Now if you refresh Master UI, you can see the new worker listed under Workers section.
Repeat the command to add multiple workers to the same master.